# Elasticsearch return data not correct?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have the elasticsearch document like this

```
{
  "_index" : "sokhop",
  "_type" : "jobs",
  "_id" : "14",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "job_salary" : "2000000 - 10",
    "job_bonus" : "> 5909990",
    "job_location" : [ {
      "province_name" : "tay ho",
      "district" : "",
      "province_value" : "Tay Ho",
      "street" : "",
      "province_id" : 130,
      "number" : "",
      "job_id" : 14
    } ],
    "job_created_at" : "2016-10-14T10:01:45.000Z",
    "job_exclude_condition" : [ ],
    "job_expired_time" : "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "job_skills" : "",
    "job_owner_id" : 2,
    "job_position" : {
      "pos_value" : "LTV",
      "pos_id" : 1,
      "pos_name" : "ltv"
    },
    "job_time_type" : 2,
    "job_isactive" : 1,
    "job_description" : "",
    "job_categories" : [ ],
    "job_year_exps" : "1 Năm",
    "salary" : {
      "job_allowance" : {
        "min" : 4000000,
        "max" : -1
      },
      "job_bonus" : {
        "min" : 5909990,
        "max" : -1
      },
      "job_salary" : {
        "min" : 2000000,
        "max" : 10
      }
    },
    "job_gender" : 1,
    "job_status" : 2,
    "job_languages" : [ {
      "lang_name" : "english",
      "lang_code" : "en",
      "job_id" : 14,
      "lang_id" : 1,
      "lang_updated_at" : "2016-10-08T09:47:49.000Z",
      "lang_created_at" : "2016-10-08T09:47:49.000Z"
    } ],
    "job_id" : 14,
    "job_extra_desc" : "",
    "job_allowance" : "> 4000000",
    "job_require_condition" : [ ],
    "job_work_location" : "[{\"district\":\"\",\"province\":130,\"number\":\"\",\"street\":\"\"}]",
    "job_updated_at" : "2016-10-18T03:20:38.000Z",
    "job_language_profile" : "en",
    "job_title" : "Tin",
    "job_position_id" : 1
  }
},
```

**My query using to search is**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "job_location.province_id": "130"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "job_position.pos_id": "1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "salary.job_salary.min": {
              "gte": 20000
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "salary.job_salary.max": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> Ok it working fine ! but when change condition to

```
         "gte": 50000
```

**or 300000,40000 every number not start with 2 elasticsearch immediately return empty array []**

**UPDATE**

> Here is all result come from my elasticsearch
> ==> [elasticsearch_result](http://pastebin.com/8H69xBgb)
>
> **How i can reslove it?**

Comment: It might be because your `salary.job_salary.min` field is of type string instead of long. Can you update your question with what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/sokhop/_mapping/jobs`?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Note that I asked for your mapping, not the results, see the curl I gave you.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/B6DeA6En here is my mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your mapping, the issue is that your `salary.job_salary.min` field is a type string.

```
"job_salary":{"properties":{"max":{"type":"string"},"min":{"type":"string"}}
```

A `range` query on a string field will not sort numeric values in numerical order, but in lexicographical order, i.e. "50000" comes after "2000000000"

The only way to fix this is to delete your index and create a proper mapping with appropriate data types.

```
DELETE sokhop

PUT sokhop
{
    "mappings": {
      "jobs": {
        "properties": {
          "job_allowance": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "job_apply_number": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_apply_numbers": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_bonus": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "job_categories": {
            "properties": {
              "jca_created_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "jca_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "jca_name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "jca_updated_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "jca_value": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "job_id": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "job_company_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_created_at": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "job_description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "job_exclude_condition": {
            "properties": {
              "jexca_created_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "jexca_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "jexca_name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "jexca_updated_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "jexcon_value": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "job_id": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "job_expired_time": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "job_extra_desc": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "job_gender": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_isactive": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_language_profile": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "job_languages": {
            "properties": {
              "job_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "lang_code": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "lang_created_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "lang_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "lang_name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "lang_updated_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              }
            }
          },
          "job_location": {
            "properties": {
              "district": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "job_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "number": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "province_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "province_name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "province_value": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "street": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "job_owner_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_position": {
            "properties": {
              "pos_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "pos_name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "pos_value": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "job_position_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_quantity": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_range_allowance_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_range_bonus_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_range_salary_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_require_condition": {
            "properties": {
              "jexca_created_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "jexca_id": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "jexca_name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "jexca_updated_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "jexcon_value": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "job_id": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "job_salary": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "job_skills": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "job_status": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_time_type": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_title": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "job_updated_at": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "job_views_number": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "job_work_location": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "job_year_exps": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "salary": {
            "properties": {
              "job_allowance": {
                "properties": {
                  "max": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "min": {
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                }
              },
              "job_bonus": {
                "properties": {
                  "max": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "min": {
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                }
              },
              "job_salary": {
                "properties": {
                  "max": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "min": {
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then you need to reindex your data and your query will work as expected afterwards.