# Elasticsearch querystring range syntax returning 0 results when it should return some results? tested with multiple ranges

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am creating a simple Elasticsearch query_string trying to get ranges of numbers across various fields. It seems some ranges I use gets me results BUT when I expand it or shrink it I get 0 results for some reason... Please see below:

I have the following simple querystring query:

```
{
"query":{
  "query_string": {
     "query" : "[33344455555 TO 33344455555]"
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns Hits total = 4 which is CORRECT.

If I expand the range on left to :

```
{
"query":{
  "query_string": {
     "query" : "[1 TO 33344455555]"
    }
  }
}
```

Which I get 12 results which is expected.

Now I extend the range on right:

```
{
"query":{
  "query_string": {
     "query" : "[33344455555 TO 2233344455555]"
    }
  }
}
```

I get 8 results which is still OK

BUT here are the issues I have:

```
{
"query":{
  "query_string": {
     "query" : "[33344455555 TO 3334445555522]"
    }
  }
}
```

I get 4 results which is weird because 3334445555522 is greater than 2233344455555 so I should get 8 results at least.

Also another issue :

```
{
"query":{
  "query_string": {
     "query" : "[654654 TO 3334445555522]"
    }
  }
}
```

I get 0 results...
I am really confused about this - I am searching all the fields in this query afaik - maybe I am not understanding the range query syntax on query_string documentation:
**Ranges can be specified for date, numeric or string fields. Inclusive ranges are specified with square brackets [min TO max]**

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: It might be that the fields you're checking on are string fields. In this case, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124058/elasticsearch-return-data-not-correct/40124636#40124636 (hint: on string fields, it's not working like you expect, i.e. 2 < 10 is not TRUE)

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. But what can i do to have bother the original value (used for display in UI) and a numerical value for search if I only get one value as input?

Comment: Maybe you can try to have 2 separate fields. One for UI & one for querying.

Comment: i created a "fields" field that has the parsed number but it is still in string due to analyzer. I am not sure how to get it to be a number unless i have to change the input to have 2 inputs?